# wso2 is, is there a method to have a reset service?

Tags: service, oauth, reset, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have to create a client application that uses OAuth2 and a REST service. I confirmed that the REST service I can achieve it only by WSO2 ESB? WSO2 IS does not provide any REST service without using other platforms carbon?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some rest webservices for oauth2, check https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
and the associated doc 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Resource+Owner+Password+Credentials+Grant

Comment: You should be able to use any standard REST client library for this.

Comment: Have you a few example? I confused ideas very now